# Full path to self in DOS executable

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

In my 16bit DOS program I want to get the full path to the instance of my program, using DOS interrupt or its internal tables.
In other words, I'm looking for **DOS equivalent of Windows API function [GetModuleFileName(NULL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)**

Interrupt  [21h/AH=60h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-3137.htm) seemed to be a right track but 
it fails when the program is not in current directory. I made a simple test program:

```
MYTEST PROGRAM FORMAT=COM
    MOV AH,60h    ; TRUENAME - CANONICALIZE FILENAME OR PATH.
    MOV SI,MyName
    MOV DI,MyFullName
    INT 21h       ; Convert filename DS:SI to canonizalized name in ES:DI.
    MOV AH,09h    ; WRITE STRING$ TO STARNDARD OUTPUT.
    MOV DX,DI
    INT 21h       ; Display the canonizalized name.
    RET           ; Terminate program.
MyName     DB "MYTEST.COM",0 ; The ASCIIZ name of self (this executable program).
MyFullName DB 256 * BYTE '$' ; Room for the canonizalized name, $-terminated.
  ENDPROGRAM MYTEST
```

It was created as "C:\WORK\MYTEST.COM" and run in DOSBox on Windows 10/64bits:

```
C:\WORK>dir
MYTEST   COM     284 Bytes.
C:\WORK>mytest
C:\WORK\MYTEST.COM      REM this works as expected.
C:\WORK>d:
D:\>c:mytest
D:\MYTEST.COM           REM this is wrong, no such file exists.
D:\>
```

Does anybody know a way how to get argv[0] in 16bit assembler program?

Comment: Note that `argv[0]` and “Full path to self in DOS executable” are different things.  I'm not sure how to get either though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on DOS version you might use the undocumented fact that the file name can be found after the environment variables. Such as:

```
org 100h

    mov ax, [2Ch]    ; segment of environment from PSP
    mov ds, ax
    xor si, si
findloop:
    cmp word [si], 0 ; one zero for end of string, another for end of table
    lea si, [si+1]
    jne findloop
    lodsb            ; skip end of table
    lodsw            ; number of additional strings (?)
    cmp ax, 1
    jne error
    mov ah, 2
printloop:
    lodsb
    test al, al
    jz done
    mov dl, al
    int 21h
    jmp printloop
done:
error:
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
```

At least in dosbox this gives the full path. Under different OS you might need to combine with the current directory or even search `PATH`, if it works at all.

Comment: Yes, it works both in EXE and COM formats, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**You can obtain this info from looking at the DOS environment.**

The PSP of your program contains amongst other things - at offset 002Ch - the segment address of the DOS environment. The environment is filled with a bunch of ASCIIZ strings and terminated by an additional zero.

Then comes a meaningless? word that you must skip.

Hereafter you can find the full pathspec to your running program.